# Choice of Data Structures

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, hashtable

I've found the question below in the CS GRE sample test but can't be sure if it's a) or e) Can anyone point out which one it is?

Thanks in advance

Which data structure would be most appropriate to implement a collection of values with the following three characteristics?

Items are retrieved and removed from the collection in FIFO order.
There is no a priori limit on the number of items in the collection.
The size of an item is large relative to the storage required for a memory address.
A) Singly-linked list, with head and tail pointers B) Doubly-linked list, with only a head pointer C) Array D) Binary tree E) Hash table

Comment: This should really be tagged `homework` - the `array` and `hashtable` tags are probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Items are retrieved and removed from the collection in FIFO order.
2. There is no a priori limit on the number of items in the collection.
3. The size of an item is large relative to the storage required for a memory address.

Given requirements 1 and 2, I'd say a [**Singly-linked list**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly.2C_doubly.2C_and_multiply_linked_lists), with head and tail pointers is your best bet.  You can insert elements quickly with the tail pointer and remove them using the head pointer.

You can eliminate each of the other options based on one or more of the requirements.

**Doubly-linked list**, with only a head pointer - only having a head pointer makes it hard to implement the FIFO requirement.

**Array** - imposes an a priori limit on the size of the collection that other data structures do not.

**Binary tree** - doesn't organize the elements in a way that makes it convenient to implement FIFO.

**Hash table** - makes FIFO impossible.

Comment: Agreed - you *could* use an array, but you'd really be implementing a circular queue with an array as an underlying building block. It has advantages, but listing "array" rather than "circular queue" in the multi-choice options would be odd.

Comment: On your edit (pedantic) - it's possible to grow circular queues beyond the original array size simply by reallocating the array and copying. If the array size grows by e.g. doubling, this has reasonable performance for many applications - amortized O(1) per insert/delete. *NOT* something for most beginners to worry about, though.

Comment: the question says the data stored is large relative to a pointer size, so array would involve more copying on insertion, and would take up more space if the queue size is small.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a queue that is implemented as a linked list, but since that isn't an option, answer A will have to do.

B. no tail pointer means removing from the queue will be O(n) which is worse than list with head and tail pointers.

C. Would implement FIFO but "size of an item is large relative to storage required for a memory address" is a dead give away that a linked list of some kind is expected.

D. maintains sort order but not insertion order so you won't be able to implement FIFO

E. would not be correct because hash tables do not maintain order.

Comment: Pedanting : "Queue" is an abstract data type, not really a data structure. "Abstract Data Type" represents the set of values and operations. Details of how the set of values is implemented are ignored. So the set of values for a Queue ADT is a sequence of items - implementing the sequence as a linked list, an array or whatever is irrelevant to the ADT. While data structures are used to implement ADTs, they aren't really the same thing. Sometimes an ADT is named (without worrying about implementation) as a building block of a larger algorithm/data structure, though.

Comment: Yes you are right, I guess queue is really a re-stating of the question, since queue and FIFO collection are the same.

Comment: Couldn't you use a counter as the key and use a hashtable anyway? And you could use the binary tree as singly linked list without tail pointer, making deletion awkward but it would still work. (of course A remains the best answer)

Comment: My previous comment of course assumes that the binary tree is not otherwise constrained (ie not a binary *search* tree)

Comment: it was a multiple choice test so obviously the point is to pick out the best answer.

Comment: @harold - you wouldn't use a single counter - you'd use one for the bottom item and one for the top item. An advantage compared with a circular queue is that you avoid the need to wrap-around when the counters exceed the size of the underlying array - but it's an illusion, since the key-to-hash transform and hash-to-underlying-array-index lookup are basically doing that job anyway, just in an overcomplex way. Also, no resizing-the-array issues, but only because most hashtables resize their underlying arrays. IOW, what you have is basically an overdesigned and overcomplex circular queue.

Comment: @harold - you might still do it, though, in some scripting language that provides hashtables (dictionaries or whatever) but doesn't provide arrays. The only potential case I can think of is Lua - which *does* provide array-like lists, but tries to treat them as a special case of dictionaries, leading to such wierdness as a size method that gives nondeterministic results. It may be safer to rely on hashtable-like behaviour in this case rather than array-like behaviour. Personally, I prefer to simply not use Lua.

Comment: @Steve314 - yes ok, but I'm not really arguing that they're good choices, just that Kevin's "can't be used for this" statements are inaccurate

Comment: You've lost the spirit of the question by forgetting it's multiple choice. Your treating it as an essay on why any answer can be correct.

Comment: Just because it's multiple choice is no excuse to spread misinformation

Comment: @Kevin -  binary tree can not maintain sort oder; Binary search tree can; although I know the answer of this question is not "binary tree".